# Two different styles in single textview android

Tags: android, html, xml

I am trying to merge two textview with two different styles.

[image]

In above pic, How to put that curved border textview at end of above text. Means at end of (6).There is an way to do it in html but border not displaying in html.

```
String html = "<p style=\"border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000; padding: 1em;\"> B1-993m </p>";
            holder.book2.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                    html,
                            Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Above code works if we put it in html file but not working in android.it seems in android some html styles not supported.is there any way to do it or something wrong in my html with android.

[image]

Flexlayout :

[image]

Comment: will it be fast cause it comes in recyclerview

Comment: have two textview. one with normal and another with curved border background. how to put second textview at end of first textview character.

Comment: i want to be like in second image but with border like in the first image

Comment: FlexBoxlayout not helping. uploaded screenshot could you look

Comment: Things like that are usually done with spans. Indeed, all `Html.fromHtml()` really does is look for certain tags and replace them with the appropriate span type; e.g., `ForegroundColorSpan`, `StyleSpan`, etc. Unfortunately, there is no "`BorderSpan`" in the SDK, but I would bet that somebody's made one at some point. You might have a search around for one (not that specific name, necessarily), but even if you can't find an existing implementation, they're not too hard to do yourself, if you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the HTML part i don't have much idea about HTML.
What i understood from your question i think this can be done by `SpannableString` . All you have to do is create a Custom `ReplacementSpan`. To apply the Span you need to have the idea about the span indexes i.e where exactly you want to show the box .
I have tried following way . Its just a sample class to get the idea you can modify the drawing as per your need color and style everything.

```
public class BoxedSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10f, 10f, paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
}
@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    return Math.round(measureText(paint, text, start, end));
}
private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
    return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
}
}
```

here is the sample code i tried :-

```
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new
            SpannableStringBuilder("Here is some text B1-38 B2-36");
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new BoxedSpan(), 18, 23, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new BoxedSpan(), 24, stringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

Looks like it pretty much does the job . Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to use `ConstraintLayout`, it will help you arrange all view elements properly, and those two rounded `TextView` can be done with adding rounded background to them. You don't need any html marking.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better suited to using a background drawable with rounded edges for the *B1-38*

Comment: Yes but i want to start at end of above textview (at end of (6)).