# Drawing directly on TextView without altering the text property

Tags: android, textview

Can I draw something like a rectangle or a line on a TextView directly without modifying the text property (that is, not drawing those by injecting HTML code)?

**reason**:
I want to add some sort of indication for the currently spoken word by TextToSpeech to a TextView. It could be a background-colour rectangle or an underline (or any way that can indicate the word), but all the searchs result I could find were modifying the text property by substituting the word with some sort of HTML code. I am afraid that modifying the text is not that easy in my case, so I want a way to add indication without modifying the text property.

Comment: The indications you mentioned with question are doable with `Spannable` . have you tried it or you need something else other than this ? You can customize the `Spannable` as per your need also . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70518531/4168607) is one answer i made few days ago..

Comment: @ADM The TextView is already displaying an HTML content that was set by `Html.fromHtml()`, and the indication mark is not static (it has to move as the text-to-speech progresses), so I think changing the text property to accomplish that is too complicated and probably will cause errors.